# Determining average jvm metrics for set of pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I am analyzing jvm metrics on prometheus dashboard for a service deployed in kubernetes. There are several pods, each running an instance of the service.
When I do:

```
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap", app="my-application",job="my-job"}
```

This fetches all the entries for all the pods.

Now I apply sum function:

```
sum(jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap", app="my-application",job="my-job"})
```

It sums up all the results from first query.

My objective is to find average jvm statistics, which may need the number of pods running.

In grafana, I tried to search kube_* metrics, but couldn't find any suitable one.

How can I get average jvm metrics for a set of pods?

Answer (score 1):

You can get number of **running** pods by using:

```
sum(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"})
```

So your final query might look like this:

```
sum(jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap", app="my-application",job="my-job"}) / sum(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"})
```